# Regex para selecionar trecho específico

Tags: string, regex

Preciso identificar dentro de contratos as informações de nome, CPF e endereço.

A linha do locador está de seguinte maneira:

> LOCADOR:  Jose   Reinaldo Lellis de Andrade
>
> LOCADORA:   Isabel Cristina de Rezende Leme Ferreira  Andrade

Consigo selecionar a linha inteira através do código `(locador[a]?):.*\n`, porém essa expressão me retorna a palavra Locador também.

Como faço para retornar apenas o nome após a palavra `LOCADOR/LOCADORA:`?

Comment: Cada tecnologia possui sua maneira de designar e nomear grupos em expressões regulares. Se puder fornecer qual tecnologia está usando, posso melhorar minha resposta.

Comment: qual a linguagem? muitas linguagens tem peculiaridades quanto a suas implementações de regex

Answer (score 3):

Como dito na outra resposta você deve especificar qual a tecnologia está a usar.

A regex abaixo está a funcionar em um teste que realizei:

```
/locador..(.*)/gi
```

### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mP0bC2)

Comment: Genial esse regex101

Answer (score 2):

```
(locador[a]?):(.*)\n
```

Não sei qual a tecnologia que você está usando, mas basicamente você teria que pegar o nome do segundo grupo (segundo conjunto entre parênteses) e eliminar o `\n` do final.

Comment: Por que não simplificar para `locadora?:(.*)\n`?

Comment: Ele quer "locador" e "locadora". Vou colocar o `\n` no final.

Comment: Em `locadora?`, o `?` aplica-se apenas ao `a`. Mas enfim.. não faz diferença, é só para economizar caracteres. Do jeito que você escreveu talvez seja mais legível mesmo.

Comment: Você tem razão. Normalmente uso a maneira mais didática nas respostas. Neste caso vou deixar assim.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do stderr esta correta mas apenas para esclarecer o erro do teu RegEx
Foi o uso dos parenteses
eles que separam o match group, ou seja, o que você quer capturar

```
locador[a]?:(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/mP0bC2/2